# Facebook Api - Get Recent Foursquare Check ins

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-php-sdk, foursquare

I want to ask that how can i get my latest check ins on Facebook via Facebook App or Graph Api? I can get my check ins those from Facebook but can't get sended check ins from Foursquare to Facebook. Is there any way to get those check ins? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foursquare uses different locations for checkins, but they offer their own API: https://developer.foursquare.com/

They just allow to publish checkins on Facebook.